# Fourier transform lots of audio files?

Tags: bash, macos, audio, terminal

I need to batch-process some (several hours of) audio files and get their frequency/amplitude data.

I have 10 folders each containing many `wav` files and I need the average levels of each frequency from each folder. I need to get the levels of different frequencies across each folder, and computing the levels individually for each file then averaging would work, and if you know of another method please suggest it.

Is there a command-line tool (or other resource) that will compute these Fourier transforms for me?

Comment: Have a look here with SOX: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43770442/3244382

Comment: @Patrice I don't understand the output of that command. I already tried using it and asked another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47452888/play-stat-freq-what-does-the-output-mean

Answer (score -1):

You can try with SOX:

```
 sox $file -n stat -freq
```

It will output several tables of DFT (Discrete Fourier Transform). That can be a start!