# Frequency distribution from wav files

Tags: audio, terminal, sox

I found out that I can use SoX's

```
play file.wav stat -freq
```

to generate a table of levels against frequencies for a file.

However, it seems to run in real time, i.e. takes as long to complete as the audio does to play.

How can I generate the same table of frequencies and levels but in the shortest time possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of SoX is rather slow, but this is mainly caused by the displaying. One solution could be to redirect the output of SoX (which is on the *standard error* (stderr) stream in the case of *stat*) to a file.

You could use:

```
sox file.wav -n stat -freq > out 2>&1
```

that will redirect stderr to stdout (&1), and then redirect stdout to the file 'out'. See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/a/625230/624485) for other solutions to redirect stderr.

This should be rather faster (in my case few seconds for a 10 minute file).